# tree family does not work properly in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to run a prolog program that represents a tree but when I select option 1 from  menu shows me false.

Code:

https://github.com/carson314/Prolog/blob/master/menus.pl

Comment: as a first task, you should turn your predicates into proper _pure_ and _impure_ predicates where needed: pure predicates should __only__ handle the logic. They should __not__ print anything or fail to return lists or things like that. Impure predicates should __only__ handle the necessary IO and list gathering from predicates. This will tremendously help you, and us, to debug your code.

Comment: ok, thanks I'll check

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

```
opciones(X):-
(
    (X = 1) ->
    escribe("Escriba el nombre de la persona cuyo padre es que se encuentran:"),nl,
    read(X),
    escribe("Padre "),
    escribe(X),
    escribe(" es:"),nl,
    father(Z,X),
    escribe(Z),nl,
    pausa;
```

When you call `opciones(1)` then `X` is bound to `1` and because of that `read(X)` does not bind X to input from user but *checks* if user input is equal to `1`. That's first problem. The second problem is that `read/1` reads an atom while `escribe/1` needs list or character codes. You can use `atom_codes/2` to deal with it.